# How to get the value of loss in the update rule of chainer

Tags: optimization, loss, chainer

I am trying to modify a class, SGDRule(optimizer.UpdateRule) of chainer, to make my original optimizer.

To achieve what I want, I need to get not only the gradient but also the loss.

Before generating the gradient by back propagation, a forward path, which yields the loss, must be done. I need that loss.

The problem is that I have to access the loss from the code of update_core_gpu(self, param) in the class.

I learned that the Classifier object has the loss as an attribute. However, I don't know how to access the object from the update rule.

As an alternative, I considered using the Reporter object that I can access from the code. I know how to pass a value to the reporter, but have no idea about how to get the loss that the reporter has.

Does anybody know how to get the current loss in the code of update rule?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a model that holds the loss, e.g. a `Classifier`, one simple but maybe less elegant way to do it would be to simply pass the model to the `Optimizer` and then to each `UpdateRule` when being constructed in `Optimizer.create_update_rule`. If you don't want to pass the model, you could probably pass a lambda that returns the loss from the model.

Another, probably a cleaner approach if sufficient for your case, would be to implement an optimizer hook, similar to how gradient clipping is implemented in Chainer. See https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/optimizer_hooks/gradient_clipping.py#L56. You can obtain the loss via `opt.target.loss` (`opt.target` being 
your model) and for instance update the gradient prior to the optimization step.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The optimizer hook seems to be what I should try, because I hope that my optimizer can replace existing optimizers without any change in other codes. Since I'm not familier with the hook, I want to ask about it for clarification. Can I  access the loss that I get in the hook from the update-rule code? Or, should I do everything for the update rule in the hook? Thank you.

Comment: Technically speaking, since you have access to the optimizer `opt` in the hook, you could get the parameters using `opt.target.params` and for each param `p` you can get the update rule through `p.update_rule`. You can then modify the update rule as you like by e.g. storing the loss in some attributes to later access it in the update. It's a matter of separation of responsibility. The hook should ideally only do any pre/post processing related to the update, in your case, something that depends on the loss, but not the update itself (which could interfere with other hooks).

Comment: Thank you again! I’m still not sure about it, but I thought this way. In chainer/optimizer_hooks directory, I should write a hook class (myhook). When I create an object of my optimizer class, `myopt(optimizer.GradientMethod)`, I can access to the object as “self”, and I should write `self.add_hook(chainer.optimizer_hooks.myhook())`  in the initializer of myopt class. Then, I have access to both the target and the update_rule from the hook, as you wrote. Your suggestion is very helpful. Thank you.